# Bridge Movie Night #6

Tags: discussion, community-event

So, turnout for the previous Movie Night was not very encouraging. I understand that several people had time conflicts and so could not participate. For that reason, I will be posting a straw poll that will be used to determine which weekend will be best to host the next Movie Night. Be aware that all the proposed dates are in September, not August. You may select multiple dates, so long as you are able to attend.

<s>[Vote on Movie Night schedule](http://strawpoll.me/5150813). No matter the date that is selected, Movie Night will begin at 11:00 PM UTC-0 as that seems to be the most convenient time for everyone.</s>

All right, the votes have been tallied and Movie Night will take place on the weekend of **September 19-20 at 11:00 PM UTC-0**. Feel free to suggest movies and don't forget that you can vote more than once. Please consider ease of access for any suggested movie (usually availability on any streaming service, such as Google Play, Netflix, or Amazon Prime, is best).

Comment: +1 I like this idea

Comment: Doodle is better suited for this sort of thing

Comment: @badp Doodle is more useful if you want to be more flexible with times (7am, 5pm, 8pm, etc., which we don't need to be as we're having a fixed start at 11:00pm and only on weekends.

Comment: I'm good on the time. This may well be my very first Movie Night.

Comment: 11pm is 2am here :/ whatever I'll try to join

Comment: Don't expect any Americans to attend with that choice of time.

Comment: 11:00 PM UTC-0 is 6:00 pm Central Standard Time.

Comment: Wait, crap. I don't think I'll be able to make it, that's a bit too late for me.

Comment: @Yuuki I was about to correct you, but then I realized that CDT is UTC-5 instead of UTC-6, like CST is.

Answer (score 4):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: Kingsman]

***Kingsman: The Secret Service***

The world is a dangerous place and people need protecting. And that's where the Kingsmen come in. An organization of the world's most skilled top-secret spies and operatives, being a Kingsman means being the best at what you do. And it just so happens that the Kingsmen are looking for a new member. After a mission gone wrong ends with an operative dead, the Kingsmen must recruit a new member to combat the rise of a new supervillain.

Harry Hart, also known as Galahad, is one of the Kingsmen's top agents and he chooses the unorthodox Gary "Eggsy" Unwin as a potential Kingsman recruit. Now, Eggsy must survive against all odds to live up to his potential and possibly save the world.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4NCribDx4U) | [Official Site](http://www.kingsmanmovie.com/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (75%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/kingsman_the_secret_service/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated R)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2802144/parentalguide)

Comment: Very enjoyable movie. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

## Movie Suggestion: A Girl Walks Home Alone At Night

Now on Netflix!

[image: A Girl Walks Home Poster]

> The first Iranian Vampire Western ever made, Ana Lily Amirpour’s debut basks in the sheer pleasure of pulp. A joyful mash-up of genre, archetype, and iconography, its prolific influences span spaghetti westerns, graphic novels, horror films, and the Iranian New Wave.

---

> In the Iranian ghost-town Bad City, a place that reeks of death and loneliness, the townspeople are unaware they are being stalked by a lonesome vampire.

---

> Residents of a worn-down Iranian city encounter a skateboarding vampire (Sheila Vand) who preys on men who disrespect women.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YGmTdo3vuY) | [Official Site](http://www.agirlwalkshome.com) | [Rotten Tomatoes (95%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/a_girl_walks_home_alone_at_night/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Unrated)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2326554/parentalguide)

Comment: Because, y'know, I like downvotes.

Comment: Stupid question, perhaps, but where does this fall on the scary omg hide in someone's shoulder when the scary bits happen scale?

Comment: @AshleyNunn Pretty low, honestly. Much more of a western.

Answer (score -3):

### Movie Suggestion: *Slow West*

[western](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/western)[action](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action)[thriller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thriller)

[image: Slow West]

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3205376/):

> At the end of the nineteenth century, 16-year-old Jay Cavendish (Kodi Smit-McPhee) journeys across the American frontier in search of the woman he loves. He is joined by Silas (Michael Fassbender), a mysterious traveler, and hotly pursued by an outlaw along the way.

[**Trailer**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFfsTsdJfF8) | Tomato/Audience Score: [**91%/75%**](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/slow_west_2015/) | Advisory: [**R**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3205376/parentalguide) | Runtime: **84 minutes**

Availability: [**Amazon Prime**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XOX93GM)